# IExtension : extensible object pattern : How does it work?

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, extensibility

I was exploring about Extensible object pattern using (IExtension, IExtensibleObject) interfaces in C#,
I came with a very simple example to convert dates to UTC from local and vice-versa:

```
public class BaseObject : IExtensibleObject<BaseObject> 
{
    private DateTime _startDate;
    private ExtensionCollection<BaseObject> _extensions;

    public DateTime StartDate
    {
        get { return _startDate; }
        set { _startDate = value; }
    }

    public BaseObject()
    {
        StartDate = DateTime.Now;
        _extensions = new ExtensionCollection<BaseObject>(this); 
    }

    #region IExtensibleObject<BaseObject> Members

    public IExtensionCollection<BaseObject> Extensions
    {
        get 
        {
            return _extensions;
        }
    }

    #endregion
}

public class DateTimeConverterExtension : IExtension<BaseObject>
{
    private BaseObject _owner;

    #region IExtension<BaseObject> Members

    public void Attach(BaseObject owner)
    {
        _owner = owner;
        _owner.StartDate = owner.StartDate.ToUniversalTime();
    }

    public void Detach(BaseObject owner)
    {
        _owner.StartDate = _owner.StartDate.ToLocalTime();
    }

    #endregion
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BaseObject obj = new BaseObject();
        Console.WriteLine("Local Time: "+obj.StartDate);

        obj.Extensions.Add(new DateTimeConverterExtension());


        Console.WriteLine("UTC: "+obj.StartDate);

        DateTimeConverterExtension ext = obj.Extensions.Find<DateTimeConverterExtension>();
        obj.Extensions.Remove(ext);

        Console.WriteLine("Local Time: "+obj.StartDate);
    }
}
```

Output:

> Local Time: 4/13/2009 11:09:19 AM
>   UTC: 4/13/2009 5:39:19 AM
>   Local Time: 4/13/2009 11:09:19 AM
>   Press any key to continue . . .

So it works, the question is:

How does .Net framework invoke "Attach" and "Detach" when IExtensionCollection.Add and IExtensionCollection.Detach methods are invoked by the program? Fill in the internal details which I am missing here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Attach` and `Detach` methods are called by `ExtensionCollection<T>.InsertItem` and `ExtensionsCollection<T>.RemoveItem`, respectively.  These methods, in turn, are virtual methods called by `SynchronizedCollection<T>.Add` and `SynchronizedCollection<T>.Remove`, which is what your code ends up calling into.  This can be verified by using [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/).  If you created your own implementation of `IExtensionCollection<T>`, there's no guarantee that `Attach` and `Detach` would be called correctly.